# How can I determine the version of retrofit at runtime?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Is it possible to retrieve the version of retrofit at runtime? I would like to display this information in debug screen.

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: Not possible, just update some string value of it, and get it from there (a bit messy...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer assumes you're using Gradle to build your Android project. Also, I'm not a Gradle expert, so there might be drawbacks to this approach I'm not aware of.*

While there's no obvious way to do it in code, you could use Gradle to create a simple field in `BuildConfig`. Consider the following:

```
/**
 * Adds a public static String field to BuildConfig containing
 * the Retrofit version, no matter what build type is used.
 */
task createRetrofitBuildConfigField << {
    project.configurations.compile.each {
        if (it.name.contains("retrofit")) {
            android.buildTypes.each { flavor ->
                def version = it.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, "") // Removes extension.
                flavor.buildConfigField("String", "RETROFIT_VERSION", "\"${version}\"")
            }
        }
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn createRetrofitBuildConfigField
```

When you rebuild the project, a static field is added to `BuildConfig` which is easily accessible in code:

```
public static final String RETROFIT_VERSION = "retrofit-2.0.0-beta2";
```

You probably want to add the above code to `build.gradle` where the Retrofit dependency is declared.